# Facesbook games feed does not show multiple images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a simple open graph story "Assemble a puzzle".
When I assemble first puzzle Game Feed shows it as excepted (see below)
But when I've completed second and more images then small app icons displayed instead.

Screenshoyt: http://photoshare.ru/data/14/14132/1/6oaprl-68d.jpg

Why it happens? Some image size limitation or other reason?

Thanks,
Yury

Answer (score 0):

That's the beauty of open graph, it groups the activities of the app together to avoid the unnecessary flooding of the posts on wall.

User always have the option to click on the options and see the individual stories. This makes sense, right?

Comment: But these small app icons are not clickable. I can't find ability to open any one of these 2 stories... Probably I missed something.

BTW. My story is not approved yet. probably it is the reason?

Comment: No, its not related with the url, but if you carefully see, there is an option there to view the individual stories.

Comment: Can't find. Each story block is just a small app icon + 2 links "Like" and "Comment". http://photoshare.ru/data/14/14132/1/6oaprl-68d.jpg is a screenshot

Comment: Move right to " .... 2 puzzles on Magic Puzzles", there's a small down arrow, click n that and you'll say. BTW, why really you are interested in this? OG is handling the things appropriately. The recent post will be shown as the complete story and later it will be grouped

Comment: This menu contains only 1 option "Make News Feed Better":
http://photoshare.ru/data/14/14132/1/6oas8b-1pc.jpg